# iAd in multiple views

Tags: iad

look I have 1 UIView and 2 links on it to other 2 views. On key pressed I have the following:

`[self addSubview:view1]; or [self addSubview:view2];` respectively

I have used your suggestions on iAd and I have successfully achieved to show on UIView (let call it parent) iAD advertisement.

But when I navigate to view1 or to view2 iAD does not appear.

I use `[self.view addSubview:_adBannerView];` in `abcViewController.m`

what I want is to add iAd advertisement on view1 and view2 too. can you please illuminate  me how to manage this?

I will appreciate this very much.

Comment: Who are you talking to? Please try making this question more clear and try adding some code.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone was looking at this question and wanted to know how to use a single iAd ADBannerView in multiple places, this WWDC video will walk you through the entire process (note that you have to log into your developer account to view it):

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=505